# Playframework Result how check is working

Tags: java, json, playframework, httprequest

Hello I have got small problem I'm learning play 2.2.1 framework and I was making controllers like

```
public static Result Name(){
    List<Account> names = Account.find.all();
    List name = new ArrayList();


    for(Account a: names)
    {
        name.add(a.getName());
    }


    return ok(Json.toJson(name));
}
```

And in routes I added line

```
  GET           /api/name                   controllers.AccController.Name()
```

And this function gives me all names from database now I wanted to make function where i can choose what column from database name/surname/country I want to get I made something like this:

```
public static Result typewhat(String what) {


    String[] type = what.split(" ");
```

then I made if type[1] == name and same like upper but I dont know how to test now thats working or not in Routes I add line:

```
PUT      /api/findwhat         controllers.AccController.typewhat(what: String)
```

Im using Open HttpRequester and for localhost:9000/api/name it is working

but I totally dont know how to make it for this functiong typewhat

I will be very thankful for every help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PUT      /api/findwhat         controllers.AccController.typewhat(what: String)
```

for above path try

```
 localhost:9000/api/name?what=this is that
```

dont know java well but in scala it works fine

```
def typewhat(what:String) = Action { implicit request =>
   println("gs",what)
   val strAr = what.split(" ")
   println(strAr)
   Ok(strAr(0))
  }
```

Comment: if I do it like this I get in response only [], when I was testing my function on normal java class it is working good

Comment: http://localhost:9000/api/findwhat?what="name name name country"
This is working good but i dont know why this dont work for first two parameters but laters work for all i mean
"name(miss) id(miss) name(works) location(works) country(works)"

Comment: I brutally changed one thing in my function for(y=2 not y=0) and this works fine :DD